# Padding input troubles in Mozilla

Tags: html, css

I have my css, it works on Chrome but on Firefox it doesn't let me type in it, if I remove the padding inside the input it works but it's not going to fit on the design. I'm using bootstrap, I don't know if it affects.

How can I solve it?

HTML

```
<form action="" class="complete-profile__input-container">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <label for="">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Tu nombre">
      </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.complete-profile__input-container input {
    padding: 18px 12px;
}
```

**Update**

Capture:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/oQBqCp5.png]

JS Bin (Thanks to Roko C):
http://jsbin.com/gifeka/1/edit?html,css,output

Regards!

Comment: What's wrong with it? - http://jsfiddle.net/mhh6z1w1/

Comment: A JSFiddle or something would be helpful.

Comment: it might need -moz-box-sizing: border-box

Comment: For the lazy ones: http://jsbin.com/gifeka/1/edit?html,css,output ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Width and Height you provided should be greater than amount of padding for example summing top and bottom margin 18 + 18  = 36px so height should be greater than 36px, same goes for height

By applying this you will be able to type

```
.complete-profile__input-container input {
  padding: 18px 12px;
  width:180px;
  height:100px;

}
```

**Working Demo:**

```css
.complete-profile__input-container input {
  
    padding: 18px 12px;
  width:180px;
  height:60px;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" class="complete-profile__input-container">
      <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
       <label for="">Nombre: </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Tu nombre">
       
      </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, this is actually working, does input elements can not behave as divs?, Thank you so much.